# Maven - deploy static content

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

Currently I am using ANT with two different targets:

1 compile source code, create a exploded WAR file and deploy it to the appplication srv (wildfly8)

2 just copy static files (HTML/JS) into the war file on the application srv

This makes it very comfortable to develop in the frontend since the second target is very fast.

Now I want to migrate the project on maven and I dont really know how to define such targets/goals to achieve the same resuts.
So what I want to do in maven is to have to different goals: one which compiles my Java sources and deploys a new WAR file and one which just copies the static content to the exploded WAR file on the application server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve same functionality as you did with ANT

1) By default `install` goal will build war file. If  it's not working you may use https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/ and it's goal is `war:war`.

2) To achieve second target
You may use Maven Resource Plugin and it's goal `resources:resources`. You may refer http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/ and for example http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html